# netsh return value in one language

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, netsh

I want to write a program which sends `netsh` commands to PowerShell.
This program should run on all languages. But the return values of the commands depend on the language of the running Windows system.

I have found [this solution](https://itworldjd.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/how-to-change-powershell-language/) for some scripts, but it has no effect on `netsh` commands.

Is there any solution which returns English values from `netsh`?

Comment: I sense an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you want to do via `netsh`? There are probably more PoSh approaches than invoking commandline utilities and parsing their output.

Comment: I'm not surprised that `netsh` returns different error *messages* based on language, but different *return values*? Do you have any examples to back that claim?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I suppose he means command output rather than return value/exit code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers And then back to your point - consuming return values rather than command output would probably solve the issue then :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen If (and only if) the return value provides the desired information in the first place. If for instance you're trying to get an IP address or a firewall rule the return code probably won't do you any good. But even if the return code would work I'd expect WMI, PowerShell cmdlets, or .Net methods to be more suitable approaches for whatever it is the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hello guys, thank you for your answers

I want to use commands like "netsh wlan show drivers" to get information about the driver. I need the information, if hostednetwork are supported. The "returnvalue" as I call it ist a string in the language of the running system language. You know my problem now ?
PS: Also i need the command "netsh wlan show hostednetwork".

Answer (score 0):

you can change cmd codepage first by using

```
cmd /c chcp 437
```

then running netsh command in the same cmd process.

for example,

```
chcp 936 >nul 2>nul && netsh interface show interface
```

will change code page to 936 and then run netsh interface will show result in Chinese.

Comment: this won't work for languages, those codepages are compatible (e.g. from german or french or spanish you won't get english this way)